# Where does the configuraiton in /run/systemd/network come from in a fresh install of 22.04 server?

Tags: networking, 22.04, netplan, systemd-networkd

I have run the following `sudo find / -type f -name "*.network" -not -path "/var/lib/docker/*"` to show all the `.network` files on a fresh 22.04 server install.

Aside from the `.network` files under `/run/systemd/network/` I don't see any other `.network` files on the system.

Given that `/run` is `tempfs`, where is the configuration that I can see in the `.network` files  in `/run/systemd/network/` coming from, hard coded defaults in the source code of networkd?

Comment: Everything is pretty much explained here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-networkd#Configuration_files

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix There are no files in`/usr/lib/systemd/network/`, everything in `/etc/systemd/networkd.conf` is commented out, and there are no files in `/etc/systemd/network/` 

Given all of that I don't see anything in the linked article that explains where the configuration is coming from that we find in the volatile directory `/run/systemd/network/` as the contents of this directory are generated on boot and must come from somewhere else or be generated by code somehow which is what my question is trying to determine. I have edited the title to try and be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default networking setup for Ubuntu 22.04 Server is to use the Netplan utility to configure and manage networking through YAML files located in `/etc/netplan/`.

The history and general use of Netplan with Ubuntu can be read in the article, [A declarative approach to Linux networking with Netplan](https://ubuntu.com/blog/a-declarative-approach-to-linux-networking-with-netplan).

In this article, it states that Netplan will generate network configuration files in `/run/systemd/network/`.

> Netplan takes declarative YAML files from `/etc/netplan/` as an input
> and generates corresponding network configuration for the relevant
> network stack backend in `/run/systemd/network/` or `/run/NetworkManager/`
> depending on the system configuration.

The system service, **systemd-networkd**, is the backend renderer that manages networks and reads configuration files in `/usr/lib/systemd/network`, `/run/systemd/network`, and `/etc/systemd/network`.

From the [systemd-networkd man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-networkd.service.8.html):

> systemd-networkd is a system service that manages networks. It
> detects and configures network devices as they appear, as well as
> creating virtual network devices.

And...

> The configuration files are read from the files located in the
> system network directory /usr/lib/systemd/network, the volatile
> runtime network directory /run/systemd/network and the local
> administration network directory /etc/systemd/network.

---

**For a practical example:**

Look in the `/etc/netplan/` directory. There's a file named something like, `00-installer-config.yaml`. Edit this file to change your network settings. Afterwards, run `sudo netplan apply` to apply these changes. Then look in `/run/systemd/network/` directory for a file named something like `10-netplan-enp0s3.network`. Inspect the contents of this file and you'll see the changes you made in your Netplan YAML configuration file.

---

More info about Netplan can be read at the following pages:

- [Netplan.io](https://netplan.io/)
- [YAML Configuration](https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/netplan-yaml/)

More info about **systemd-networkd** can be found at the man page linked above as well as the Arch Linux Wiki: [systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-networkd)

Comment: Amazing thank you, I had no idea netplan was being used. After reading the article you linked it seems clear that on Ubuntu server I should be focused on modifying the netplan configuration files and not working with any `.network` files at all unless there is configuration not yet supported by netplan.

Comment: You’re welcome. And yes, use Netplan to configure your system.